# Print the value in enum dictionary

Tags: java

I want to print the value which I have created with the type Map dictionary

First, I have a class of Enum, then after that I define another static(I thought this will run one time when the object is initalized?), in this static, I will create dictionary for each of the enum.

Enum class:

```
public enum myEnumValues{
    testingFile1,
    testingFile2;

// this part I thought it will automatically make the dictionary based on the put I have specified? Here I use 2 put with values "check1" and "check2"

public static final Map<myEnumValues, String> var;
static{
        Map<myEnumValues, String> putting = new EnumMap<>(myEnumValues.class);
        putting.put(myEnumValues.testingFile1, "check1");
        putting.put(myEnumValues.testingFile2, "check2");
        var = Collections.unmodifiable(putting);
      }
}
```

My Test class:

```
//Is there a way to print the dictionary value for both keys "testingFile1" and "testingFile2"? I think I understand it very wrong with my method. I am still learning Java.
import folder.data.myEnumValues;
@Test public void CheckTestForMyEnumValues(){
    Map<myEnumValues, String> putting = new EnumMap<>(myEnumValues.class);
    System.out.println(putting.get(myEnumValues.testingFile1));
    System.out.println(putting.get(myEnumValues.testingFile2));
}
```

My expected result should be:

```
check1
check2
```

My goal of creating this enum dictionary class:

1) I will create another class that will have a variable a. It will then compare

```
if (x == myEnumValues.testingFile1){
    var a == myEnumValues.get(); // store the a with value for key "testingFile1".
}else{
    var a == null;
}
```

My test class is mainly for me to get the value for the key and then I will add more codes but the thing is now I could not even make a dictionary with enum and also I could not even know whether the dictionary is made and call the value of each enum. That is why I created this question.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create the Map inside the enum? Maybe you should create it in your Test class.

Comment: Yes, I am sure because of my use case is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the map that you've created in the `static` block for accessing the values. Don't create a new map because the new map contains nothing.

```
@Test public void CheckTestForMyEnumValues(){
    System.out.println(var.get(myEnumValues.testingFile1));
    System.out.println(var.get(myEnumValues.testingFile2));
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get this error; cannot find symbol.

Comment: It solved, I just have to add the myEnumValues.var.get then it will solve it. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You can print both keys and values for all entries within a map with following single line (Java 8)

```
putting.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format("Key: %s, value: %s", k, v)));
```

Comment: You mean in the test class? But then I receive error: could not find symbol for "putting"

Comment: Replace 'putting' with the whatever you are referring your map with in your test class or wherever you want to print the key value pairs for all entries.